How to prevent Microsoft Word Equation editor from turning `min` into the function?
I'd like to write min^2 to represent the unit "minutes squared", but every time I write min in the Microsoft Word equation editor it tries to turn it into the function, written in non-Italics. How do you enter it without it being turned into the function?

You can undo the automatic change to the min function by either clicking the Undo button in the ribbon, or by pressing Ctrl+Z.  Do this immediately after the text "min" is auto-converted to the min function and it will let you continue your equation.

If I do this, it leaves the space, so when I go to type ^2 it doesn't add the square. Edit: if I use the ^ instead of the space it works.

Word is converting the equation to Professional format. To stop this happening automatically, open the Equation Options at the bottom corner of Conversions.

Then uncheck Automatically convert expressions to professional format and click OK.

If you only want to remove auto-formatting for min, click the Recognized Functions... button in the Equation Options. Then search for min and delete it.


This affects all other formatting - is there a way to undo it for min only?

@Adam Updated the answer. You can choose which Recognized Functions get auto-converted. Removing min from the list prevents it from being converted.
